# any other hardware items needed?

Tags: kinect, xbox

I recently bought a xbox 360 bundle with kinect.I would like to start programming with kinect but not sure if I need any other hardware interface to connect kinect with my computer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two versions of the Kinect, one requires some additional hardware to connect to a computer, one does not. If you got yours in a bundle, you'll probably need an extra cable.  Check out this article:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/kinectsdk/thread/e98786bb-560e-4603-9d08-67033d58c51a/